# OpenVPN don't route internet traffic just local

Tags: openvpn

I have a VM with an SQL server,web service and a OpenVPN (https://datawookie.netlify.app/blog/2018/09/diy-vpn-with-docker).

I only want to use the VPN to connect to the SQL server and the web service. I don't want to route internet traffic. I added to my client config:

```
pull-filter ignore redirect-gateway
route-nopull
route-noexec
```

But this way nothing gets routed. what do I need to do to accomplish my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming web is 192.168.2.10 and sql is 192.168.3.10, push those subnets

at this step:

```
docker run -v $OVPN_DATA:/etc/openvpn --log-driver=none --rm kylemanna/openvpn ovpn_genconfig -u udp://VPN.SERVERNAME.COM
```

you would add

`-p "route 192.168.2.10 255.255.255.255" -p "route 192.168.3.10 255.255.255.255"`

full command:

```
docker run -v $OVPN_DATA:/etc/openvpn --log-driver=none --rm kylemanna/openvpn ovpn_genconfig -u udp://VPN.SERVERNAME.COM -p "route 192.168.2.10 255.255.255.255" -p "route 192.168.3.10 255.255.255.255"
```

you could add whatever network, ip and mask for these values, so if you want an entire subnet 192.168.2.0/24 that would be `-p "route 192.168.2.0 255.255.255.0"`

you could also use env vars, see https://github.com/kylemanna/docker-openvpn/issues/565